# Get and post data from Google Spreadshets via Google Script

Tags: javascript, php, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm developing HTML5 app and I want to read/write some data from/to Google Spreadsheets.

**Attempt 1. Pure JavaScript**

I tried to call a webservice situated in .gs file on Google Script.

```
gapi.auth.signIn({
    'clientid' : 'MY_CLIENT_ID',
    'cookiepolicy' : 'single_host_origin',
    'callback' : 'loginCallback',
    'scope' : 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds'
});

$.get('https://script.google.com/macros/s/APP_CODE/exec');
```

This only works for one .gs script. For another .gs script I get error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'domainname.xx' is therefore not allowed access." According to Google API documentation it's not allowed to call functions in .gs files remotely with AJAX. How to make them work?

**Attempt 2. PHP application as proxy**

I managed to authenticate with Google using OAuth 2 but how to send GET/POST requests as authenticated user? Can I access functions in .gs files or spreadsheets directly?

```
// OAuth getting the token - works fine
$params['client_id'] = self::OAUTH_CLIENT_ID;
$params['response_type'] = 'code';
$params['scope'] = self::OAUTH_SCOPE;
$params['redirect_uri'] = self::OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI;
$this->response->redirect('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?'.  http_build_query($params));

// OAuth exchange tokens - works fine
$fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.googleapis.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
$postData['code'] = $_GET['code'];
$postData['redirect_uri'] = self::OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI;
$postData['client_id'] = self::OAUTH_CLIENT_ID;
$postData['client_secret'] = self::OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET;
$postData['scope'] = '';
$postData['grant_type'] = 'authorization_code';
$postContent = http_build_query($postData);

$out  = "POST /oauth2/v3/token HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$out .= "Host: www.googleapis.com\r\n";
$out .= 'Content-length: '.strlen($postContent)."\r\n";
$out .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n";
$out .= $postContent;

fwrite($fp, $out);
$response = strstr(fread($fp, 4096), '{');
```

How to call doGet() and doPost() functions from .gs files as authenticated user? If it's impossible, how to read and write to spreadsheets on Google Drive?

Comment: Please read the official docs. Seems like you totally skipped all documentation. look at the htmlService and how to call a server function then look at spreadsheetApp

Answer (score 0):

You can access a *published* Apps Script with an HTTP Request.  You can't directly call a function in an Apps Script from an HTTP Request.  You *could* make a GET/POST request to an Apps Script; send data in a search string at the end of the URL, and have the `doGet()` or `doPost()` function "decide" what functions to run depending on what was sent in the search string, and then return the appropriate response.  So, in that sense, you could get different functions to run with that method.
Take a look at the **Content Service** documentation:
[Apps Script - Content Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/content-service)

If you decide to use PHP, you could use Apps Script as an intermediary between your site and a Google spreadsheet, but if you can figure out the PHP Client API, just use that.